# Conformally flat slices in Kerr spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric

I heard some references to ''conformal Kerr'' in general relativity and I'm not sure what this means.

It presumably cannot be referring to a conformally flat slice of Kerr spacetime, since the Kerr metric does not admit such a hypersurface.

If one takes the $t=0$ slice in the Kerr spacetime, is this $3$-metric conformal to another simpler metric?